# Probability density function and probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have to answer a question on an assignment, and I am not entirely sure what the question is asking, let alone how to answer it.

Suppose $X$ has a Pareto distribution with density $$f(x)=\frac{ab^a}{x^{a+1}}\, \text{for}\, x \geq b,\,a > 0,\, \text{and}\, b>0. $$

The question actually states "clarify the density function $f$ and the two concerned probability measures".

I'm not entirely sure what is meant by "clarify" here, but if what some of my classmates had to say is true, what he wants us to do is talk about how the density function is a measurable function that maps events $A$ in the sample space $\Omega$ (in the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field containing $A$, and $P$ is a probability measure) to subsets of $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{L})$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal{B}$ are the Borel sets.

Are the probability measure and the Lebesgue measure the two probability measures that are meant here, and what does it mean for $f$ to be the density between them?  Thank you.

Comment: That's just a poorly worded question.  Nobody here can give you clarification on this: we aren't inside your instructor's head!  Check in with the person who assigned you the problem.

Comment: @NickPeterson I tried. I sent an email around noon and have had no response. But, let's say my instructor meant how does the pdf relate the two probability measures? Then what?

Comment: Maybe they want to know the CDF (which is $P(X\le t) = 1_{[b,\infty)}(t)\left(1-\left(\tfrac b t\right)^a\right)$).

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp In my notes, I found the following: For measurable spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mu)$ and $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \nu)$, if there is some non-negative measurable function $\delta$ on $\Omega$ such that $\nu(A) = \int_{A}\delta(\omega)d \mu \geq 0$ for any $A \in \mathcal{F}$, then the measure $\nu$ is said to have a density $\delta$ w.r.t. the measure $\mu$. Now, I think the two measures in question here are the probability measure for a Pareto distributed r.v. and the lebesgue measure, so I guess I just have to show that $X$'s density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure is $f$?

Comment: No, that's actually the only fact that is given to you.

Comment: @NickPeterson he just got back to me: he said: "A density is introduced to achieve some mission. I mean to clearly detail this mission."

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp see the comment I just made.

Comment: @DaenerysDracarys I'd say "Mission Impossible". ;-) Seriously, I don't know what this guy means.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I really think it's what I said earlier - I think he wants a verbal explanation of what mathematically is going on here. Weird, but not terribly surprising.